# How to calculate sum of a vector till a specific index using accumulate() in c++

Tags: c++, accumulate

I would like to know if there is anyway to perform Sum of a vector till specific index using `accumulate()`. Example

```
vector<int> v ={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int sum = accumulate(v.begin(), till_index_4, 0);
```

All examples i found says `accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);` I tried with iterator also but my code is not compiled. Please let me if there is any possible solutions available.

Comment: *"tried with iterator also but my code is not compiled"* Can you show us that code?

Comment: parameters are not indices but iterators. You really just have to include 1 or 2 more lines of code and the error message to make this more answerable

Comment: `std::accumulate` doesn't know that you're providing data from a `vector<int>`. It applies to a range, delineated by two iterators. So just give it iterators for the range that you're interested in.

Comment: `accumulate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 4, 0);` is what I _think_ you're asking for?  That code assumes the range is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ standard library provides function `std::next` which takes an iterator into a sequence, and yields another iterator `n` steps apart. For `std::vector` iterators this is an O(1) operation.

If you know that `n`-th position in your vector is valid, you can accumulate as follows:

```
int sum = accumulate(v.begin(), std::next(v.begin(), 4), 0);
```

Comment: Or simply `v.begin() + 4`